# Waiting for JButton to be pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm new to Java programming.

I want to make a menu for my game. I use Swing for the GUI. I've made the required frames.

The program starts with the main menu, that should be waiting for JButton to be pressed. I've made ActionListener for each JButton, but I can't manage to make the program to wait one of them to be pressed.

I want my menu to work like this:

If you press the newGameB, the menuFrame closes, and the gameFrame starts to act. If you press the exitB, the program should close itself.

I've read about using wait() and notifyAll(), but I couldn't do it to make the program work properly.

```
public class Main {
public enum CurrentState{
    MENU, GAME, EXIT
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CurrentState currentState = CurrentState.MENU;
    boolean isRunning = true;
    while(isRunning) {
        switch(currentState) {
        case MENU:
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            menu.runMenu(currentState);
            break;
        case EXIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        case GAME:
            System.out.println("game");
            PlayGame game = new PlayGame();
            game.runGame(currentState);
            break;
        default:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MenuFrame extends Frame {
CurrentState currentState;

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel();

JButton continueGameB = new JButton("Folytatás");
JButton newGameB = new JButton("Új játék");
JButton scoresB = new JButton("Eredmények");
JButton exitB = new JButton("Kilépés");

public void setCurrentState(CurrentState state) {
    currentState = state;
}

public MenuFrame(CurrentState currentState) {
    this.currentState = currentState;
    
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel);
    
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    panel.setBackground(background);
    
    panel.add(continueGameB);
    panel.add(newGameB);
    panel.add(scoresB);
    panel.add(exitB);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void runFrame() {
    openFrame();
    exitB.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    newGameB.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == exitB) {
            setCurrentState(CurrentState.EXIT);
        } 
        else if(e.getSource() == newGameB) {
            setCurrentState(CurrentState.GAME);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Menu {
MenuFrame menuFrame;

public void runMenu(CurrentState currentState) {
    this.menuFrame = new MenuFrame(currentState);
    menuFrame.runFrame();
}
```

}

```
public class Frame {
JFrame frame;
Color background = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);

public Frame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Progházi");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setUndecorated(true);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(background);
}

public void openFrame() {
    frame.pack();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void closeFrame() {
    frame.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: `wait()` and `notifyAll()` are definitely not what you want to be using. Don't loop in your `main` method; create the UI and show it.  You will then write code to respond to events in the UI.  Here is a very good, concise tutorial on creating a Swing application that will show you the correct way to create a Swing application: https://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/lect/l7/

Comment: Here's Oracle's tutorial: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: I'm really curious and I would very much appreciate it if you posted links to the Web sites you visited that showed you how to write a game in _Swing_

Comment: @Abra This game is just a text based game, where you read a story and you choose between two answer options and go on, so it doesn't require much graphics. I only use JLabels and JButtons at this point. So I've just only read about these kind of things, like how to make a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a volatile boolean variable which is set to true when an ActionEvent occurs at the JButton. Given this you could have a section in your code where a while loop executes until one of the buttons is pressed.

Furthermore, you could have multiple boolean variables to detect which button is pressed and call certain methods based on this.